# How to write jpql query for subquery with multiple conditions and other relationships

Tags: postgresql, jpa, hql, jpql

I want to fire following query through JPQL.I am new to JPA and learning JPQL but stuck at this query.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM applicants)
AND gender = 'MALE' AND (firstname like '%R%' OR lastname like '%S%');
```

Here gender and name parameters are passed dynamically but here i kept it static.

My Classes Snippets are:
This is my user class
**User Class:**

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long userId;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

private String firstName;

private String middleName;

private String lastName;

private String gender;

private Timestamp appliedOn;
}
```

Applicant class has OneToOne relationship  with User class and join column is userid.

**Applicant Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "applicants")
public class Applicant{

@Id
private long applicantId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "subCourseId")
private SubCourse course;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "collegeId")
private College college;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't what you want to achieve achievable with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN applicants ON users.userid = applicants.userid
WHERE applicants.userid IS NULL
AND gender = 'MALE' AND (firstname like '%R%' OR lastname like '%S%');
```

Or a NOT IN:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM applicants)
AND gender = 'MALE' AND (firstname like '%R%' OR lastname like '%S%');
```

If yes, you should probably find your answer starting from there.

Comment: yeah i should use queries in this way thanx

Comment: Hello Ridham, if you are satisfied with that answer, please mark it as best, so that the community knows this question has been treated. Thank you :)

Comment: Now that's sad, but I'm pretty sure you do, you only need 1: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts "Mark as accepted answer" :D

Answer (score 0):

JPQL query for that SQL

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM applicants)
AND gender = 'MALE' AND (firstname like '%R%' OR lastname like '%S%');
```

will be the next:

```
String jpql = "SELECT us FROM User us WHERE us.userId NOT IN (SELECT appl.user.userId FROM Applicant appl) AND us.gender = ?1 AND (us.firstName LIKE ?2 OR us.lastName LIKE ?3)";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jqpl);
query.setParameter(1, "MALE");
query.setParameter(2, "%R%");
query.setParameter(3, "%S%");
query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks mate working completely fine.I was confused in alias